# How to add nested columns in a LibreOffice writer table?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to add a nested column inside the selected cells as they have plenty of space to use. I'm using the **LibreOffice 6.3**

[image: WRITER]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. With the cells selected, go to *Table* → *Split Cells...*.

   [image: Table -> Split Cells...]
2. On the *Split Cells* window input the desired number of cells you want to split them to, select the desired split direction and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

   [image: Split Cells window]

Comment: Thank you for so good explanation!!!